# Easy way to send PHP language array files to translation?

Tags: php, arrays, localization, translation, locale

I'm using Laravel PHP framework, and like everyone else I have language files that are actually php files with a big array in them.

Does someone know a friendly way of getting these files to translators?
Is there an editor or some service maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What google proposed:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

It can import PHP translation files and has a neat interface for easy editing of translations.

Simply install the package through composer, and translate away!

Answer (score 0):

- Another webapp: http://zanata.org/help/translation/translating/
- A nice desktop app: http://poedit.net/

Kind regards,
Benedikt